# 'validates_presence_of' doesn't work well in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

There are two classes:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  embeds_many :addresses
end

class Address
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :city
  field :street

  validates_presence_of :city, :street
end
```

We can see, we have validated the `city` and `street` should be present.

But see following code:

```
person = Person.new
person.addresses << Address.new
person.save #-> true
```

And, we use `mongo` to see the database directly:

```
$mongo
> use the_db
> db.people.find()
{"_id":"xxxxx", "addresses":[{"_id":"xxxxx"}]}
```

The address has been inserted. That means `validates_presence_of :city, :street` in `Address` is not worked.

Do I miss something? Or there is a bug in Mongoid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  embeds_many :addresses

  validates_associated :addresses
end


class Address
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :city
  field :street

  embedded_in :person
  validates_presence_of :city, :street
end
```

now i think if you try to save the address then you wont be able to save person
Because validates_assocaited :addresses tries to validate address before saving person.
Hope this works